# When should we flag an answer?

Tags: discussion, flagging

<sup>I am sorry for a series of questions on this topic recently. This will be the last question I promise :)</sup>

Recently I flagged some answers. The following flags are disputed:

- [How to vertically center a table on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489419/156344)

  **Reason:** The answer is seriously lacking information. But... it is accepted.
- [Numbers in bold inside a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489651/156344)

  **Reason:** The answer is [clearly wrong](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8282/156344), as it is what the OP had tried.
- [Increase LaTeX table row height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489924/156344)<sup>1</sup> (now deleted by owner)

  **Reason:** The answer is [a duplicate of a competing answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8294/156344)<sup>1</sup>.
- [Can I create music sheets with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490035/156344)

  **Reason:** The answer has nothing to do with the question. It does load `musixtex` which is related to music, but I can't find a bit about music inside `\begin{document}...\end{document}`.

As those flags are disputed, I know I am flagging in a wrong way. But how wrong it is? In what case should we flag an answer?

I am looking for a general answer for the last question above.

---

<sup>1: Only available for users having 10k+ rep.</sup>

Comment: The "music sheets" link seems to be an attempt to use the `abc` music creation package, so it's not fair to say it has "nothing to do with the question". But I agree there are so many things wrong with it that it is useless as an *answer* to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flagging is intended for cases where 'user' actions cannot suffice. For example, an objectively wrong answer can be downvoted: that's how the site is supposed to work. On the other hand, an answer with is about a totally different topic, or is itself a question, should really be removed entirely: that requires moderator action.

I would not get hung up too much on whether your flags are 'helpful'. Some of that can be affected by review queues, etc., and there can be a 'diversity of views'. The helpfulness of flags is mainly there to allow the back-end to order flagged posts for mods: we have a sufficiently-short queue that this is really neither here nor there.